# Почему я получил шляпу 2020?

Tags: дефект, новогодние-шляпы

В описании говорится

> опубликуйте сообщение в чате ±12 часов от Нового Года по UTC, которое получит звезду

Но до нового года больше 3 недель - как может быть 12 часов?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339927/348096

Comment: Это описание неплохо бы поправить- перенести "сообщение" к запятой. А то сейчас звезду получает UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пофиксили. Шляпу отобрали, но у тех, кто её носит, она продолжает отображаться на аватарке. При этом, если других шляп нет, то её нельзя снять или подвинуть (по крайней мере, через интерфейс сайта).

[image: скриншот]

[image: скриншот]