# Со шляпами "шляпа" 2020

Tags: обсуждение

Почему у кого-то отображается количество шляп, а у кого-то нет?!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть подозрение что за награду не дают шляпу! )

Comment: У меня тоже подозрение, что со шляпами что-то не так... Помню, что в прошлых годах у меня был сразу 10-ок шляп, а сейчас только 1 секретная, хотя, вроде, задания не поменялись...

Comment: @Grundy слишком хорош :)

Comment: Поразительно как все эти блестяшки влияют на людей...

Comment: Да, уже традиция вестись на шапки и активный вести себя к нг на so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это [ошибочно выданная шляпа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9841/178988). Её отобрали, но с аватарки убирать не стали.

Количество шляп не отображается, если шляп нет.

Comment: А что такое вообще "шляпа"? У меня значок появился, но написано "Вы еще не заработали ни одной шляпы".